# Swift - Recorded Video is Mirrored on Front Camera - How to flip?

Tags: swift, avcapturesession, avcapture

I'm trying to mirror the recorded video from a capture session. The video preview for front facing camera shows a mirrored version, however, when I go to save the file and play it back, the captured video is actually mirrored. I'm using Apple's AVCam demo as a reference and can't seem to figure this out! Please help.

I've tried creating an AVCaptureConnection and trying to set the .isVideoMirrored parameter. However, I get this error:

> cannot be added to the session because the source and destination media types are incompatible'

I would have thought mirroring the video would be much easier. I think I may be creating my connection incorrectly. The code below doesn't actually "Add connection" when I call the .canAddConnection check.

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated) 

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
//Setup Camera
 if let dualCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .front) {
                defaultVideoDevice = dualCameraDevice

            } else if let frontCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front) {
                // If the rear wide angle camera isn't available, default to the front wide angle camera.
                defaultVideoDevice = frontCameraDevice
            }
            guard let videoDevice = defaultVideoDevice else {
                print("Default video device is unavailable.")
               // setupResult = .configurationFailed
                captureSession.commitConfiguration()
                return
            }
            let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)

if captureSession.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) {
                captureSession.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
            }

let movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
//Video Input variable for AVCapture Connection 
let videoInput: [AVCaptureInput.Port] = videoDeviceInput.ports

if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
                captureSession.beginConfiguration()
                captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
                captureSession.sessionPreset = .medium
```

Then I try to setup the AVCapture connection and try to set the parameters for mirroring. Please tell me if there is an easier way to mirror the output / playback.

```
 avCaptureConnection = AVCaptureConnection(inputPorts: videoInput, output: movieOutput)

 avCaptureConnection.isEnabled = true
 //Mirror the capture connection?
 avCaptureConnection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
 avCaptureConnection.isVideoMirrored = false
 //Check if we can add a connection
 if captureSession.canAddConnection(avCaptureConnection) {
 //Add the connection                  
 captureSession.addConnection(avCaptureConnection)
  }

  captureSession.commitConfiguration()
  self.movieOutput = movieOutput

 setupLivePreview()

        }
  }
```

Somewhere else in the code, connected to an IBAaction, I initialize the recording

```
// Start recording video to a temporary file.
    let outputFileName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let outputFilePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent((outputFileName as NSString).appendingPathExtension("mov")!)
    print("Recording in tap function")

    movieOutput.startRecording(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: outputFilePath), recordingDelegate: self)
```

I think I'm using AVCaptureConnection incorrectly, especially because of the error stating media types are incompatible. If there is a proper way to implement this function please do let me know. Also open to hearing suggestions for an easier way to mirror the playback. Thank you!